# Exit status -15

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, airflow

While working with Apache Airflow, I had a DAG which stores some events in postgresql table. So while execution of the DAG, It is failing time and again and it shows me this : -

```
 subprocess.CalledProcessError:
```

Also it shows me exit code of -15

Can someone help me out,
Thanks.

Comment: The -15 most probably means that the subprocess got a SIGTERM. Any reason why your system would try to kill the process?

Comment: Even I am getting a pg connection timeout issue on create table commands.